# simplify code using a list in python

Tags: python

I have a line of python code that basically asigns a integer to a string (one letter). Since I use if statements, it need a lot of code lines... Is there a way I could simplify my code using a list so that it doesn't take up  63 lines of code? Here's my code:

```
if character in " ":
    character = 0
elif character in "Aa":
    character = 1
elif character in "Bb":
    character = 2
elif character in "Cc":
    character = 3
elif character in "Dd":
    character = 4
elif character in "Ee":
    character = 5
elif character in "Ff":
    character = 6
elif character in "Gg":
    character = 7
elif character in "Hh":
    character = 8
elif character in "Ii":
    character = 9
elif character in "Jj":
    character = 10
elif character in "Kk":
    character = 11
elif character in "Ll":
    character = 12
elif character in "Mm":
    character = 13
elif character in "Nn":
    character = 14
elif character in "Oo":
    character = 15
elif character in "Pp":
    character = 16
elif character in "Qq":
    character = 17
elif character in "Rr":
    character = 18
elif character in "Ss":
    character = 19
elif character in "Tt":
    character = 20
elif character in "Uu":
    character = 21
elif character in "Vv":
    character = 22
elif character in "Ww":
    character = 23
elif character in "Xx":
    character = 24
elif character in "Yy":
    character = 25
elif character in "Zz":
    character = 26
elif character in ".":
    character = 27
elif character in ",":
    character = 28
elif character in "?":
    character = 29
elif character in "'":
    character = 30
else:
    character = 0
```

Comment: I'm going to suggest that while it's possible to replace this with any of the answers below, it's really obvious what this code does, and not necessarily as obvious what the other code does. Also if you need to add ñ or ç to your original solution it's obvious how to do that.

Comment: @JoshRumbut I guess if you don't know what the `ord` function or `.get`   do then maybe. But you could just put a comment above it. Why write 60 lines when you can write 6 lines and a comment and be just as clear

Comment: This reminds me of https://github.com/AceLewis/my_first_calculator.py/blob/master/my_first_calculator.py

Comment: @Keatinge maybe, in either case putting it in a well named method with a comment is a good idea. Not sure how many people remember what that 96 does off the top of their head, and it still requires hardcoding the last few values. There's also the issue of what to do if some of the characters change the value they're associated with, become associated with the same value, or if perhaps Cyrillic letters need to be handled as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Simply set range by setting ASCII value using ord() function and then find index using index() function.

```
TestCase='T'

# Make all Input to lowercase.

TestCase=TestCase.lower()


#calculate ASCII value of all lower character String

RangeVariable=range(ord('a'),ord('z'))

#Now Returning required Index value by comparing ASCII value of Testcase with that in RangVariable


print(RangeVariable.index(ord(TestCase)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Put all of the characters into one big string where the characters' positions in that string are the values you want to assign. You can handle upper and lowercase letters by converting the input to lowercase first.

```
value = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,?'".find(character.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a *dict* with *str.lower*:

```
d = {" ":0, "a": 1, "b": 2, ......,"'":30}

character = d.get(character.lower(), 0)
```

If *character* is not in the dict the default value will be `0`although I don't see the logic of setting a space to 0 and also having that as a default.

To create the dict as per @user23571152 comment:

```
d = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(" " + string.ascii_lowercase + ".,?'")}
```

Comment: Rather than explicitly writing out that huge dict, you could do something like `d = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(" " + string.ascii_lowercase + ".,?'")}`.

Comment: @user2357112, yep, I was more showing the logic but I added your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to code all those letters a-z by hand...
If it's alpha, subtract 97 from the ord, otherwise `.get()` from the dict with a default of 0 if its not in the dict

```
specialChars = {" " : 0, "." : 27, "," : 28, "?" : 29, "'" : 30}
char = "'"
if char.isalpha():
    print(ord(char.lower())-ord('a')+1)
else:
    print(specialChars.get(char, 0))
```

This makes two calls to ord per char, I don't know how your actual function works but ideally you would just calculated `ord('a')+1` one time and use that per character. Or you could just use `print(ord(char.lower())-96)` if you are okay with the magic number

Comment: @Barmar I don't see a better way to write it. 96 is just the number you have to use to get a = 1 b = 2. Do you really think this code would be more clear with some variable on the top called `valueToSubtractFromOrd` equal to 96. It's not a meaningful number

Comment: `ord(char.lower()) - ord('a')+1`.

Comment: @Barmar Now every single letter requires two calls to ord though, one of which getting the same value every time.

Comment: `base = ord('a')-1` then use `ord(char.lower()) - base`.

Comment: @Barmar alright fair enough, I've edited it with the first way

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea:

```
character = ord(character.lower()) - ord('a') + 1 if character != ' ' else 0
```

You can adapt it to your particular requirements on the input. Since you didn't specify the acceptable domain of input values, I'm assuming that input is limited to what's in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `dict` like so:

```
In [0]: import string

In [1]: keys = list(" ") + list(string.ascii_lowercase)

In [2]: dict = {}

In [3]: for v, k in enumerate(keys): dict[k] = v

In [4]: def getCharVal(character): return dict.get(character.lower(), -1)

In [5]: getCharVal("B")
Out[5]: 2
```